# How to expand a tableview cell in Xamarin.iOS native platform?

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios

I am trying to develop an application in Xamarin and I need to expand the tableview cell, but I don't have any idea about it. Can any one tell me hoe to implement the expandable/Collapsible table cell in Xamarin.ios?

Answer (score 0):

There are several samples and tutorials you can refer to, you can also try to do it yourself:

- Insert some rows or sections when you want to expand your tableView:
  `tableView.InsertRows(new NSIndexPath[] { }, UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic);`
- When you want to collapse try to use delete method:
  `tableView.DeleteRows(new NSIndexPath[] { }, UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic);`

You can see these posts for more details:

[TableView expanding and collapsing section with animation on touch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29823259/tableview-expanding-and-collapsing-section-with-animation-on-touch)

[Create expandable tableview in Xamarin.iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40403031/create-expandable-tableview-in-xamarin-ios)

And samples:

https://github.com/b099l3/StackOverflow/tree/master/ExpandableTableView
https://github.com/TheEightBot/EightBot.AutoExpandAndCollapse
https://github.com/brminnick/ExpandableList
https://github.com/iSofTom/STCollapseTableView